# Using Apache as a debug proxy for https traffic

Tags: proxy, apache-http-server, ssl, https

I know that I should be using mitmproxy (or Charles, or Fiddler, or Burp Proxy), and that I can use Squid, but is it possible to use Apache to debug out going https traffic from my computer? That is, see the decrpyted http requests?

Thanks!